# QObject selfdestruction aware container

Tags: qt, containers, qt5, qobject, self-destruction

Is there a Qt container, that is aware of the destroyed signal of QObject and removes the element if an element was destroyed?

I.e. like this:

```
QObject *obj1 = new MyObject();
QObject *obj2 = new MyObject();
QObjectContainer c;
c.add(obj1);
c.add(obj2);
qDebug() << c.size(); // Prints 2
delete obj1;
qDebug() << c.size(); // Prints 1
```

Comment: Wait, you have a flaw in your idea. If you delete an object, how would you find its index in the array? You'd need to perform a full search each time. Think about it, it can't be implemented in any reasonable way. Even if your array catches the `destroyed()` signal, it gets only the address of the pointer, not its index in the array. You'll need to search it by value. The performance would be awful.

Comment: Add your objects as children of a dummy parent QObject ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself by catching signal `destroyed()` inside `container`-derived class.

P.S. No Qt class does this, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

QPointer will auto clear itself when the object pointed to is deleted

Comment: Well thats fine bit is there a list which will remove the QPointer if the contained object pointed to is deleted.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r you can do some bookkeeping during iteration, though a indexed list is probably not a good idea instead a set-like container would be better.